# Certificate chain validation

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

How  I can make certificate chain validation in java or open ssl?
I am writing app where it is very common scenario for users to put the wrong sequence of chain. Certificates are imported in *.pem format.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEDDCCAvSgAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBiDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIExDCCA6ygAwIBAgIJAJGR2RC4vX04MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGcMQswCQYD
f3sCZkch3E3Cb9GTBCq/c39A5ay6xj4b
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I do not care if certificate is valid or not, only that they are in right order imported!

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
openssl verify -verbose -purpose sslserver -CAfile <file containing both root and intermediates> <file containing signed cert>
```

> If successful, you’ll get back a response like : OK
>
> If unsuccessful (or something is missing), you’ll get back a response
>   like:
>
> Error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: Thank you very much man! Which is the signed cert if user imports chain? Is it the last one? In my app I have fields for private key, and one field for chain. User is able to import unlimited encoded certificates. How I can separate them from signem cert? First one should be root, last one signed cert, am I right?

Comment: @user2739823 you can refer [this](http://shib.kuleuven.be/docs/ssl_commands.shtml) and [this](http://jw35.blogspot.in/2010/05/doing-certificate-verification-in.html) for more details, but i think you can play around with the answer now, you have the command with you. :)